# How can I use nginx reverse proxy to setup my local website to do api request

Tags: nginx, web, cross-domain, reverse-proxy

Now I have only a localhost website: localhost:8080

and I need to call api cross-domain
Here are two backend api url:

1. www.example.com/api/site/login
2. www.example.com/api/site/register

How can I setup reverse proxy at local using nginx?